# efficient ways to structure large code fragments

Tags: android, eclipse

I have couple of initialization classes that do nothing else but to fill initial unchanged data structures. In total about 200k lines in 5 data Classes just doing things like:

```
   x = new Y(13);
   xTmp.z.add(x);
   allElements.add("just some text");
```

So basically initializing arrays of my structures - these are all basically "constants".

I was wondering how to best structure the project, for example using libraries or doing anything else so the development of the project can be handled more efficiently than to always compile, link and load the large data classes to the device for testing.

Forunately Eclipse is real fast and compiling takes not more than 1 minute (compared to xCode where it takes over 1,5 hours to compile). However, I am sure the experts with experience of writing large projects have thir tips and tricks how to best get their hands around it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't hard code all that data at all.

Define a file format for all that data, and build a simple parser for it (or better yet, use an existing structured file format and drive from that). There is no reason to have to rebuild your code when you change the initial data.

Bundle those initialization files with your application (you can even put the inside your jar files and access them as resources).

Comment: All that data is confidential and encrypted - I am afraid that once the data is in a file it would be easily hacked. Any kind of database or file structure can relatively easily be opened and understood with the appropriate tools. That's why I put the data in the code directly in such a way. Also, this way the time for the app to start is really short - amazingly not noticeable at all what is going on before the first screen appears - and this on a really slow device.

Comment: What makes you think putting that data in a `.class` makes it less hackable than in a plain text file? If you use the right config file format, loading it could be _faster_ than parsing those humongous dataclasses.

Comment: I would expect that finding even the different data/class areas and within the variables that hold the data in compiled code would be harder than opening a file - not talking about the decryption. However, I have to admit I never tried to understand compiled Java code. Anyway - what would be a good approach to factor out some big pieces of code?

Comment: Compiled java code is very easy to decompile (as long as you don't want to recompile the decompiled code, just analyze it). **Much** easier than say C or C++. How you split up big classes is completely up to you, depends on what the classes do, and how coupled they are. But seriously, large "constant-container" classes are not the way to go IMO.

Comment: I see, actually I am coming from C++ and assumed it would be similar in Java. Thanks for making this clear!. Just out of interest - what tool could I try to decompile my code and see how it looks like and what can be easily extracted?

Comment: I've used jad in the past, mocha is another one. Just search for "java decompiler", some are even integrated in IDEs.